# Ошибка "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, type-error

Я новичок, поэтому не сильно разбираюсь. Пытаюсь создать чарт.

```
def get_symbol_names():
# connect to MetaTrader5 platform
mt5.initialize()

# get symbols
symbols = mt5.symbols_get()
symbols_df = pd.DataFrame(symbols, columns=symbols[0]._asdict().keys())

symbol_names = symbols_df['name'].tolist()
return symbol_names
```

Когда запускаю этот файл, всё нормально. Но, когда пытаюсь указать функцию 'get_symbol_names' в другом файле, выдаёт ошибку:

```
File "c:\Users\artco\OneDrive\Desktop\app\application.py", line 16, in <module>
options=[{'label': symbol, 'value': symbol} for symbol in get_symbol_names()],

 File "c:\Users\artco\OneDrive\Desktop\app\mt5_funcs.py", line 25, in get_symbol_names
symbols_df = pd.DataFrame(symbols, columns=symbols[0]._asdict().keys())

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Вот проблемный код:

```
symbol_dropdown = html.Div([
html.P('Symbol:'),
dcc.Dropdown(
    id='symbol-dropdown',
    options=[{'label': symbol, 'value': symbol} for symbol in get_symbol_names()],
    value='EURUSD'
)
])
```

Comment: Импортируйте нужную вам функцию

Comment: Она импортирована с помощью строки 'from mt5_funcs import get_symbol_names, TIMEFRAMES, TIMEFRAME_DICT'